# jQuery not working straight away

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on Ruby on Rails and a simple jQuery won´t execute over an element like this:

```
$("header").hide();
```

However, if i wrap it into a function and call it with document.ready it does the right thing:

```
function myCode() {
    $("header").hide();
}

$(document).ready(myCode);
```

Why it does not work straight forward?? I have installed gem jquery-rails and even have //=required jquery.min.js in the application.js file.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Why should it work until the document is loaded?

Comment: *"Why?"* Element has to exist when you run that code. Pretty basic fundamental of javscript and dom manipulation. Same as you can't eat a pizza that hasn't been delivered yet

Comment: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If the document is not ready, the DOM isn't built yet. The `header` element doesn't exist when that code runs, so nothing happens. To perform DOM manipulation, you must wait until the page is fully loaded, that is, on `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Not entirely accurate. Whole dom doesn't necessarily need to be loaded. Can place that code immediately after the element without `$(document).ready` and will work fine

Comment: That's true, thanks for the correction!

Comment: i am confused.. so you say this should work straight ahead as the first line of code for application.js? $("header").hide();

Comment: Yes and no. Strictly it works, but there's no guarantee that the DOM object exists at the time of its execution. You can either do it when the document is `ready`, or perform the script *after* the code that creates the header element.